# JFreeChart customise axis range?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to plot the average runs for each ball in a Twenty20 cricket match, on a JFreeChart. This means the X-Axis would need to start at 0.1 and go to 19.6. This I can do fine, however using the standard tick units means I get:
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1 etc, whereas it should go:
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.1 etc. (As there are only 6 balls per over)

This becomes a problem when I'm doing things like lines of best fit.

Does anyone know if I can implement a custom axis like this? I've had a look at CyclicAxis but I'm not sure if that's quite the same.

Comment: CategoryAxis may be what you're looking for

Comment: Also consider `SymbolAxis`.

Comment: Hmm, I've managed to get it working with category axis, just naming the categories 0.1, 0.2 etc, however there are now far too many ticks to display the labels properly (120 of them). Is there any way I can only display every 6th tick?